# Print MaterialUI Dialog fullscreen

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-tsx

I am new to React and Material-UI and I want to print my current dialog.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to maximize my Dialog for priting (set to fullScreen) without doing it in the Browser, too. So I basically want a smaller Dialog in my Browser and for the Dialog the maximal size.

Here is my basic code in TSX:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Button, Dialog } from '@material/core';

export default class MUITester extends Component {

 render(){
   return (
      <Dialog fullScreen={false}>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => window.print()}>
            PRINT            
          </Button>
         </div>
       </Dialog> 
     );
   }
```

And the corresponding css file:

```
@media print {
   .print {
       fullScreen=true;
       color: blue;
    }  
}
```

Can I solve it using css? Or do I have to use React/Material-UI?

Comment: So you don't want to use the `fullScreen` prop of the Dialog component? Or what are you trying to achieve properly?

Comment: I'm trying to get the `fullScreen` prop to true, only when I am printing like
`@media print { .print { fullScreen : true; color: blue; }  } `
and in the Browser it should be false.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it! Change the classes of Dialog:

`<Dialog classes={{paperFullScreen: "prePrint printDialog"}} fullScreen>`

Here my css:

```
.prePrint {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 600px !important;
}

/*Print Dialog*/
@media print {

    .printDialog {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a full-screen Dialog on mobile and a simple dialog for desktop and the below example resolved my issue, please take a look if helps.

```
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

function MyComponent() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));
    return <Dialog fullScreen={fullScreen} />;
}
```

You can check demo on MUI [official documentation](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/#responsive-full-screen).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of your dialog like this:

```
<Dialog  fullWidth={true} maxWidth='md'>
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => window.print()}>
        PRINT            
      </Button>
     </div>
    </Dialog>
```

As given in the [Documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

For printing div, which is inside dialog, use below code, and add css also

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Button, Dialog } from '@material/core';

export default class MUITester extends Component {

 render(){
   return (
      <Dialog classes={{paperFullScreen: "prePrint"}} fullScreen>
        <div id="DialogPrint">
           some text some text , some paragraph and so on 
         </div>
         
          <div >
              <Button onClick={() => window.print()}>
                PRINT            
              </Button>
         </div>
         
       </Dialog> 
     );
   }
}
```

add below code in css

```
.prePrint {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 600px !important;
}

/*Print Dialog*/
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #DialogPrint,
    #DialogPrint * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #DialogPrint {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add fullScreen flag to modal [component](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/) in order to achieve full screen.

Like below

```
<Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
```

And if you don't want to use fullScreen, simply remove that fullScreen flag and don't need to use CSS here.